# jdbc setLoginTimeout does not work

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need help with jdbc driver for mysql. I need to set connection timeout. java claims it's done by `setLoginTimeout` of the `DriverManager` class. but this method seems to not work.

Whatever value I put, say 15 seconds: `setLoginTimeout(15)` it will always timeout after 10 seconds always. Even if I `getLoginTimeout` it always return 0.

Some will ask why I need this, it's because when I click a button that performs a CRUD, I need to show progress of whatever insert, delete, etc through a thread. but how do I do it since `DriverManager.getLoginTimeout` returns 0 seconds but when run its actually 10 seconds.

I really need help, i have been searching all over, some say just `setLoginTimeout` but this method is not responding

Comment: I don't see how not being able to set the connect timeout affects your ability to display progress. You don't have all that much ability to do that anyway, really: you can only show when the connect, prepare, execute, close happen. I wouldn't have thought that was very interesting to a user.

Comment: You don't want to create a connection for each action. Where possible, reuse a the connection and the prepared statement. The crud operation will probably take 10s of ms, creating a statement could take 100ms, whereas establishing a connection could take a second. I don't know how you are going to show progress of a single transaction. If it is a longer running batch, state can be updated in another table and the state can be periodically queried from another thread, but this does not seem to be your use case.

Comment: guys all i need is being able to set time out, the rest is handled, im using a connection pool, reusing connections.

Comment: ejb it has to, in real world u cant have a timeout of 10 seconds. it has to be longer. for example u cant be paying for using ur credit card and connection time out in 10 seconds, that application is unusable

Answer (score 1):

The *login timeout* is not the same as a connection timeout. The login timeout (if supported by the JDBC driver) applies to creating a connection and logging in only and as you comment that you already use a connection pool, then this is not the property you are looking for.

To specify the connection timeout (or blocking timeout), you need to check the specific connection properties available for your JDBC driver, eg for [Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) it is `socketTimeout`.

Also be aware that the configuration of your server may also influence how long the actual timeout may be.